# Google Scholar: get links for cited papers(not cited by)

Tags: citations, google-scholar

This may seem like a stupid question, but I have been looking for this for quite some time and haven't found anything helpful. I want to download all papers cited within a given paper. Is there such a feature available in Google scholar? Or even just a page listing all the cited paper links?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming.